# Database error 1054 following update to 2.7.0

Tags: error, database, ee2-upgrades, multiple-sites

I've just updated a staging instance of EE to 2.7.0 from 2.5.2 following a successful update of a development instance and the live production instance. The reason for update was because we have MSM installed with four sites and needed to update to support a fifth.

I'm upgrading MSM from version 2.1.4 to 2.1.6.

Following the update three of the four sites function correctly but the fourth displays the following error with debugging enabled:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 't.dst_enabled' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT t.entry_id, t.channel_id, t.forum_topic_id, t.author_id,
>   t.ip_address, t.title, t.url_title, t.status, t.dst_enabled,
>   t.view_count_one, t.view_count_two, t.view_count_three,
>   t.view_count_four, t.allow_comments, t.comment_expiration_date,
>   t.sticky, t.entry_date, t.year, t.month, t.day, t.edit_date,
>   t.expiration_date, t.recent_comment_date, t.comment_total, t.site_id
>   as entry_site_id, w.channel_title, w.channel_name, w.channel_url,
>   w.comment_url, w.comment_moderate, w.channel_html_formatting,
>   w.channel_allow_img_urls, w.channel_auto_link_urls,
>   w.comment_system_enabled, m.username, m.email, m.url, m.screen_name,
>   m.location, m.occupation, m.interests, m.aol_im, m.yahoo_im, m.msn_im,
>   m.icq, m.signature, m.sig_img_filename, m.sig_img_width,
>   m.sig_img_height, m.avatar_filename, m.avatar_width, m.avatar_height,
>   m.photo_filename, m.photo_width, m.photo_height, m.group_id,
>   m.member_id, m.bday_d, m.bday_m, m.bday_y, m.bio, md.*, wd.* FROM
>   exp_channel_titles AS t LEFT JOIN exp_channels AS w ON t.channel_id =
>   w.channel_id LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data AS wd ON t.entry_id =
>   wd.entry_id LEFT JOIN exp_members AS m ON m.member_id = t.author_id
>   LEFT JOIN exp_member_data AS md ON md.member_id = m.member_id WHERE
>   t.entry_id IN (744) ORDER BY t.sticky desc, t.entry_date desc,
>   t.entry_id desc
>
> Filename: modules/channel/mod.channel.php
>
> Line Number: 288

I've tried restoring the database and config files and re-running the installer and I've also tried clearing all the caches via the control panel as per the suggestions in [this thread on the Elis Lab forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/235596/). Incidentally I am posting as MaryMalphurs on that thread (client account).

I've checked that the config file has the version number as "270" I've double checked the index.php MSM config entries.

I'm at a total loss now so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
 Alex

Comment: Does this error appear throughout the site, or just on a particular page? (That query references a particular entry - #744).

Comment: @DerekHogue error for the main index.php. Although I did do some further digging and found that the unknown column was present before the update. So I wonder if the error is more related to the filesystem as opposed to the database i.e. the query that's being generated is flawed rather than the database has a missing column.

Comment: Yeah, the 'dst_enabled"column was removed I think in 2.6.

Comment: Interesting. That points even more at the problem lying in the query generation then.I've had to roll back to previous stable version due to commercial pressures to keep things alive. I'll see if I can re-run the whole process again next week.